# NSTableView getting blank

Tags: sqlite, nstableview

I'm trying to get results from a SQLite database into a NSTableView, containing rows and columns, using Swift.
There is no problem with the database query and I'm getting no errors when running the application.
However, the table always remains blank.
What is missing in my code?
Thanks in advance

This is my code

```
class SecondViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableview: NSTableView!
    
    var querySQL = ""
    
    var bdadosDB: OpaquePointer?
    
    var statement: OpaquePointer?
     
    var allRows = [String]()
    
    var rows = [String]()
    
    var cols = [String]()
    
    let CellIdentifiers :[String] = ["ordCell", "procCell", "espCell", "natCell", "recCell", "estCell", "julgCell", "decCell"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
       let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,  .userDomainMask, true)
       let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
       let databasePath = (docsDir as NSString).appendingPathComponent("bdados.db")
       let dbpath = databasePath
       sqlite3_open(dbpath, &bdadosDB)
        
       querySQL = "SELECT * FROM proc"
        
       sqlite3_prepare_v2(bdadosDB, querySQL, -1, &statement, nil)
        
       while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
         {
          let str = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)) + ";"
          let str_1 = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)) + ";"
          let str_2 = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)) + ";"
          let str_3 = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)) + ";"
          let str_4 = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)) + ";"
          let str_5 = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)) + ";"
          let str_6 = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)) + ";"
          let str_7 = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7)) + "_"
          
          let result = str + str_1 + str_2 + str_3 + str_4 + str_5 + str_6 + str_7
          allRows.append(result)
        }
        
        let str_arr = allRows.joined(separator: " ")
        rows = str_arr.components(separatedBy: "_")
        
        tableview.dataSource = self
        tableview.delegate = self
        
    super.viewDidLoad()
      }
    
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
       
        return allRows.count
     }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

     var text: String = ""
     var cellIdentifier: String = ""
       
     for i in 0 ..< rows.count
       {
      let rw = rows[i]
      cols = rw.components(separatedBy: ";")
      
      for j in 0 ..< cols.count {
        let col = cols[j]
        text = col
        if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[j] {
          cellIdentifier = CellIdentifiers[j] }
        }
     }
       
    if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: cellIdentifier) , owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
         cell.textField?.stringValue = text
         return cell }
     else {
       return nil }
     }
    
    func reloadFileList() {
       
        tableview.reloadData()
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `tableview.reloadData()` after setting `dataSource` and `delegate`?

Answer (score -1):

It was a problem with cell identifiers.
Now it's working - but I always get the same (last) table row.
Is it possible to put and execute the delegate function within the for loop ?